# Can I generate an API documentation using spring-restdoc?

Tags: spring-restdocs

I'm using spring-restdoc to document my restful services. I'm now moving on and also want to expose the events I publish. What would be a proper way to incorporate these in the document?

I've come up with writing a class similar to `RestDocument`, with could take an `Class` as an argument and you could document all the properties of that class through a similar fluent interface.

Comment: Can you provide some more details about the events that you publish and how they are published?

Comment: They are objects that are serialized as json to a message queue.

Comment: for api documentation you can use SpringFox Swagger, this is easy to use Please find the basic project setup [here](https://github.com/sehramadhvi88/spring-swagger) it's a small demo , to view json go to http://localhost:8093/v2/api-docs and for UI go to http://localhost:8093/swagger-ui.html